# ILog Elixir clock example.

Tags: apache-flex, ilog-elixir

I am trying to use a clock example on [the following website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/elixir/entry/clockwidget1?lang=en).

Everything in the clock is working expect for the hour hand. The hour hand stays on 12 all the time.

I have used the entire code as it is. changed nothing in it. The clock is working fine on the example page.

Can some one help me with this issue?

Zeeshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a 24h format machine, add "%12" in the setTime method:

```
hourNeedle.value = h%12;
```

Hope this helps,